# Runge Kutta4 in python for complex system

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a complex system where you can visualize it as some points/nodes where a spring-damper system is connected in between those nodes, each point carry the forces from all other connected springs and dampers in addition to the gravitational forces on them since each spring and damper have a specific mass.
I'm using classes to make the grid and the initial conditions, but i'm not sure how exactly to calculate the new positions and accelerations using the runge kutta 4
this part is where runge kutta is defined

```
rows = 5
columns = 6

class Runga_kutta4():
def __init__(self, node, u0, v0, t):
    
    self.u0 = u0
    self.v0 = v0
    self.t = t
    self.u = u = 0, 0
    
    self.ux = u[0]
    self.uy = u[1]

    self.v = v = 0, 0

    self.vx = v[0]
    self.vy = v[1]

    f = Forces(u0, u, v0, v)
    self.Node_Forces = f.nodeforces(node)

    self.dt = t[1] - t[0]
    results = self.calculation()
    return results

# Returns the acceleration a
def acceleration(self, Node_Forces):
    """
    F = m *a
    a = F/m
    F_sys = F_externe - (F_damping + Springs) - F_g
    """
    a_list = []
    for (f, m) in zip(Node_Forces, Masses.Lattice_Mass()):
        ax = f[0]/m[0]
        ay = f[1]/m[1]
        a_list.append((ax, ay))
    return a_list.reshape(5, 6)

def calculation(self):

    for i in range(self.t.size - 1):
        # F at time step t / 2
        f_t_05_x = (self.Node_Forces[0][i + 1] - self.Node_Forces[0][i]) / 2 + self.Node_Forces[0][i]
        f_t_05_y = (self.Node_Forces[1][i + 1] - self.Node_Forces[1][i]) / 2 + self.Node_Forces[1][i]

        u1x = self.ux[i]
        v1x = self.vx[i]
                    
        u1y = self.uy[i]
        v1y = self.vy[i]
        
        a1x = self.acceleration(self.Node_Forces[0][i])
        a1y = self.acceleration(self.Node_Forces[1][i])
        
        u2x = self.ux[i] + v1x * self.dt / 2
        v2x = self.vx[i] + a1x * self.dt / 2
        
        u2y = self.uy[i] + v1y * self.dt / 2
        v2y = self.vy[i] + a1y * self.dt / 2

        a2x = self.acceleration(f_t_05_x)
        a2y = self.acceleration(f_t_05_y)
        
        u3x = self.ux[i] + v2x * self.dt / 2
        v3x = self.vx[i] + a2x * self.dt / 2
        
        u3y = self.uy[i] + v2y * self.dt / 2
        v3y = self.vy[i] + a2y * self.dt / 2

        a3x = self.acceleration(f_t_05_x)
        a3y = self.acceleration(f_t_05_y)

        u4x = self.ux[i] + v3x * self.dt
        v4x = self.vx[i] + a3x * self.dt

        u4y = self.uy[i] + v3y * self.dt
        v4y = self.vy[i] + a3y * self.dt

        a4x = self.acceleration(self.Node_Forces[0][i + 1])
        a4y = self.acceleration(self.Node_Forces[1][i + 1])
        
        self.ux[i + 1] = self.ux[i] + self.dt / 6 * (v1x + 2 * v2x + 2 * v3x + v4x)
        self.vx[i + 1] = self.vx[i] + self.dt / 6 * (a1x + 2 * a2x + 2 * a3x + a4x)
        self.uy[i + 1] = self.uy[i] + self.dt / 6 * (v1y + 2 * v2y + 2 * v3y + v4y)
        self.vy[i + 1] = self.vy[i] + self.dt / 6 * (a1y + 2 * a2y + 2 * a3y + a4y)

        self.u = (self.ux, self.uy)
        self.v = (self.vx, self.vy)

    return self.u, self.v


l = Lattice(3)
t0, te, dt = 0, 3, 0.001                            # s
t = np.linspace(t0, te, round((te-t0)/dt + 1))

for node in l.latticeNodes():
    position0 = 0, 0
    velocity0 = 0, 0
    state0 = np.append(position0, velocity0)
    new_state = Runga_kutta4(node, position0, velocity0, t)

visualise(l)
```

[photo of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpF1Z.jpg)

Comment: There exists a library called [```scipy```](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html) (which is pretty standard) that solves ODE's and has some runge-kutta methods. Specifically I would rely on their implementation of [runge kutta 4](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html#scipy.integrate.RK45) as a comparison starting point. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) is a working example of scipy's ODE solver.

Comment: i don't want to use this library since i'm working with different dimensions and different equations, so that's why i wrote my own function, but it's not working

Comment: Ok cool - can you write down the system of differential equations in latex and add a picture of the equations to your question?  That would make it alot easier to understand what you are trying to do. If the system of equations is clearly written, its much more likely for someone with DiffEqn experience to swoop in with the right library/advice/codefix to help you.

Comment: okay, so i'm trying to use a different approach now by making the runge kutta method for one node only instead of a grid of nodes 
so my code now looks like

Comment: i edited the main code in the question